# Rails 5x instance of the model cart which will necessarily be linked to a user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, e-commerce, cart

i am a beginner

how to create an instance of the model cart which will necessarily be linked to a user.

the projet it is a creation of store e-commerce ^^

Best regard !

Comment: Rails e-commerce?  here: https://github.com/spree/spree.
cart: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/promotion_handler/cart.rb.
order: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/order.rb

Comment: Ok thanks but i prefer tutorial ^^